# How to get information for fps for a video file in properties menu? (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: file-properties

I want to find information on fps for video easily, Can I display that in properties menu after right-clicking on file?

How to find it?

Comment: It's already there on the Audio/Video tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view this in the Audio/Video tab of the Properties window of Nautilus:
[image]